# Problems with lists and multiplication table

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting

I need to build a function that takes two positive integers and returns a list of lists representing a multiplication table for multiplying all integers from 0 up to the given number. So for example, `times_table(3,5)` should return

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0,  0,  0], 
 [0, 1, 2, 3,  4,  5], 
 [0, 2, 4, 6,  8, 10], 
 [0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15]]
```

However, the function can only do this : `4 = 4 , 8 , 12 , 16`.  Also, I cant figure out how to make it in (x,y) format.

---

This is what I have so far:

```
def times_table(s):
    n=int(input('Please enter a positive integer between 1 and 15: '))
    for row in range(1,n+1):
        s = ''
    for col in range(1,n+1):
        s += '{:3} '.format(row * col)
    print(s)
```

Help if you can...

Answer (score 1):

You could do it this way:

```
def tables(a, b):
    return [[i*x for x in range(b+1)] for i in range(a+1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
num = int(input("enter you number - "))
table = [num*i for i in range(1,11)]
print(table)
```

**Explaination** -
Creating multiplication table using list comprehension.

1. num will take the input value of the user
2. creating a list "table" where input value gets multiplied by i (item) for numbers from 1-10 (for python we need to put +1 to the end value in range)
3. the for loop keep multiplying the num value from 1-10(which is i) and you will get the desired table

*Learned this concept from Code With Harry advance python course in youtube*

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehensions:

```
def times_table(y,x):
    return [[xi*yi for yi in range(x+1)] for xi in range(y+1)]

y = input("Enter y: ")
x = input("Enter x: ")
print(times_table(y, x))
```

(Attached with input)

Comment: then how can i make this a user input so that they can make their own dimensions?

Comment: @JaredBanton pass it to the function! (see the times_table(3, 5)? Just put the user input there and you're gold!)

Comment: can you use an example please? Im new at this

Comment: now it's saying that x and y are not defined variables

Comment: @JaredBanton you probably missed a few things. I formatted the code above (copy-pasting it as a whole would work)

Answer (score 0):

Python (pseudo-)code:

```
def times_table(times,factor):
    table = [[0]*(factor+1)]
    for i in range(1,times+1):
        table.append(list(range(0,i*factor+1,i)))
    return table
```

this will return the table (in array/list format) you need
then you can use pprint to pretty print it or in any other format

**Output**

```
import pprint
pprint.pprint(times_table(3,5))

[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10],
 [0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15]]
```

It would better to use the function like this:

```
n=int(input('Please enter a positive integer between 1 and 15: '))
import pprint
pprint.pprint(times_table(n,n))
```

Answer (score 0):

[List comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) are awesome.

```
def times_table(x, y):
    return [[i * j for i in range(x+1)] for j in range(y+1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is good. You are only having problem with the *indentation* in *Python*. The *for loop*s are supposed to be nested. Also if you want to include *zero* in the result, the *range* of your loop has to to start from *zero*.

```
def times_table(s):
    n = int(input('Please enter a positive integer between 1 and 15: '))
    for row in range(n+1):
        s = ''
        for col in range(n+1):
                s += '{:3} '.format(row * col)
        print(s)
```

Comment: this works, but how could i get the function to ask for input from the beginning such as (x,y) format?

Comment: You could create a main function that you can use to call the `times_table(x,y)` function, passing in the parameters in the implementation obtained from the input. 

`def main():
   x = int(input('Please enter a positive integer between 1 and 15: '))
   y = int(input('Please enter a positive integer between 1 and 15: '))
   times_table(x,y)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()`

then change the _rows_ and _columns_ range to be `x` and `y` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

The meat has already been covered by others. It looks like you're also looking to have the user input both x and y at the same time. Easiest way is:

x, y = input("enter x and y, separated by a comma: ")

If you really want the parentheses in the input, I'd input a string then pull out the values between ( and , and between , and ) and convert to integers, but that seems necessarily complex to say the least.